# Run Scripts in Powershell ISE from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-ise

I am executing my batch file which opens the Powershell ISE and loads the script but does nothing... I would still need to run manually. Am I missing something here?

BatchFile to call Powershell:

```
Powershell_ise.exe C:\Users\Desktop\myscript.ps1
```

That the code am using to monitor the file changes in a folder and to email:

```
Function Register-Watcher {
    param ($folder)
    $filter = "logfile.txt" #all files
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    $changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('
        # This is the code which will be executed every time a file change is detected
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"
        Send-email
    ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action $changeAction
}

Function Send-email{

    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $SMTPPort = "587"
    $Username = "*****@gmail.com"
    $Password = "*******"

    $to = "*****@gmail.com"
    $subject = "Email Subject"
    $body = "Insert body text here"
    $attachment = "C:\Users\Desktop\AccountMapping.sdl"

    $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $message.subject = $subject
    $message.body = $body
    $message.to.add($to)
    $message.from = $username
    $message.attachments.add($attachment)

    $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message)
    Write-Host "Mail Sent"
}

 Register-Watcher "C:\Users\Desktop"
```

Comment: why would you run it in ISE? ISE is a development environment and not for normal script execution. use `powershell.exe`

Comment: okay yeah got it, Paul. when I run in powershell.exe it's getting executed and when the file is changed an getting  `Write-Host Message` as expected but below there is a `send-mail function` it's not executing. You could see in the code

Comment: You are not calling the `Send-email` function anywhere in your script.

Comment: @dinesh Try adding `-NoExit` switch when invoking `powershell.exe`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a scope issue. `Send-Email` does not exist in the scope of the `$changeAction` scriptblock.

Comment: @Matt Not really. I've tried (after leaving only `Write-Host` inside it's body) and it works. Problem is, that `powershell.exe` without `-NoExit` switch will quit immediately after executing the script.